# Can't understand part of if/for loop

Tags: javascript

Working through a book called "head first javascript programming" and got into this practice example but I don't quite understand some part of it. I'm supposed to make it so that in console it displays the amount of tests and highest score. Here's the code.

```
var scores = [60,58,34,69,46,41,50,50,55,64,31,53,60,52,51,66,57,55,58,54,52,55,52,61,54,48,44,52,44,51,54,69,51,61,18,44];
var output;
var highScore = 0;



for(var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
  output = "Bubble solution #" + i + " score: " + scores[i];
  console.log(output);
  if (scores[i] > highScore){
    highScore = scores[i];
  }
}

console.log("Bubbles tests: " + scores.length);
console.log("Highest bubble score: " + highScore);
```

Now this code does work but I don't understand these two lines here:

```
scores[i] > highScore
highScore = scores[i]
```

Comment: So... what exactly don't you understand? How assignments and the greater-than operator work?

Comment: The problem with diving in headfirst, as the book title seems to imply, is that you miss the smart solution. You have `scores.length`, why not use `Math.max.apply(null,scores)` to get the high score, instead of manually looping, checking etc.?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I'd imagine this part of the book is explaining about loops, like the different types and is using this as a simple example. I mean as we all know, the smarter solution is to just use jQuery _sarcasm_

Comment: Haven't programmed ever before. This is the first time. I understand now, Weedoze's answer opened my eyes. Yes it's the loops, chapter 4. This is a book for beginners not learning best practices in the start it seems. It's a bit old too so things may have changed since it was published.

Comment: *Since it is a kinda selection algorithm?* @NiettheDarkAbsol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal is to know what score is the highest.

```
  if (scores[i] > highScore){
    highScore = scores[i];
  }
```

Thus while iterating over each scores. We check if the current iterating score is higher than `highScore`. If it is the case, we update the highscore with the current score.

> Iteration 1

```
scores[i] = 60
highscore = 0
--> highScore = 60
```

> Iteration 2

```
scores[i] = 58
highscore = 60
 --> highscore = 60
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (scores[i] > highScore){
    highScore = scores[i];
  }
```

This is the logic to store the highest score.

In the for each in each iteration, `HighScore` will be compared to the `score` in the current iteration.

If the current score is greater than the HighScore, then the score will be assigned to the HighScore variable.

Answer (score 1):

You use for loop to go through all the elements of the list.

At the beginning you initialize highScore to 0.

While going through the list, if current elements value is greater than value stored in highScore, assign highScore to that elements value so at the end of the loop the value stored in highScore variable will be the greatest value from the scores list.

Ex.
in the 1st loop iteration it will be

```
if(60 > 0) // which is true
    highScore = 60; // so assign value 60 to variable highscore
```

2nd iteration

```
if(58 > 60) // which is not true 
   highScore = 58; // so the value of highScore will stay 60
```

3rd iteration

```
if(34 > 60) // which is not true
    highScore = 34; // so the value of highScore is still 60
```

4th iteration:

```
if(69 > 60) // which is true
     highScore = 69; // so the value of highScore becomes 69
```

.
.
.
and so on till the end of the list.

Basically it will get the biggest value from scores list, and save it into highScore variable.

So at the end the value of highScore will be 69.